# Auto insert to all tables in DB without a need to manually implement their names

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on a database in MySQL, where I have multiple tables for players statistics like 'stats-gamemode1', 'stats-gamemode2', and so on (each has a column 'uuid', and default values for other columns implemented).

I want to **create a procedure to automate** the insertion process, like for example **registerPlayer("theUUID")**, which will insert the UUID to all tables in the database that name start with **"stats"**

I have already tried to implement a procedure like that by my self, but it is not working. Which is strange, that I receive an error: `Table 'database-name._table_name' doesn't exist.` where from unknown reason name of table = **_table_name**, but in my db i don't have the table with "**_table_name**" name.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE Finished BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE TableName VARCHAR(255);

  DECLARE TablesCursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT t.table_name 
  FROM information_schema.tables t
  WHERE t.table_schema = DATABASE() AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE' AND t.table_name LIKE "stats%";

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Finished = TRUE;

  OPEN TablesCursor;

  MainLoop: LOOP
    FETCH TablesCursor INTO TableName;
    IF Finished THEN
      LEAVE MainLoop;
    END IF;
    
    SET @queryText = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `',  TableName, '` (`uuid`) VALUES (', QUOTE(UUID_VAR), ')');
    
    PREPARE insertQuery FROM @queryText;
    EXECUTE insertQuery;
    DROP PREPARE insertQuery;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE TablesCursor;
END
```

If someone can help me to find a way to automate the insertion process i would be very glad. I need it, because i will be creating a lot of tables in the future and I don't want to edit the trigger each time to implement new table in it, I would prefer it to me automatic.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you need to normalise your design, have *one* stats table.

Comment: Do all of the tables have the same schema?